# On print background color not showing on print

Tags: php, printing

```
 <script type="text/javascript">     
        function PrintDiv() {    
           var divToPrint = document.getElementById('divToPrint');
           var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=300,height=300');
           popupWin.document.open();
           popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link href="<?php echo $temp_url;?>/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print"><link href="<?php echo $temp_url;?>/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print"><link href="<?php echo $temp_url;?>/js/item-slider/initcarousel-1.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print"><link href="<?php echo $temp_url;?>/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print"><link href="<?php echo $temp_url;?>/js/select/fancySelect.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print"></head><body onload="window.print()">' + divToPrint.innerHTML + '</html>');
            popupWin.document.close();
                }
     </script>
```

I am printing a perticular div area in php . but when i print the div all css is working only background css is not working. i tried to solve it with inline css but it's also not working.

Comment: Is this a question or a statement? Without your code nobody can help

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: i have solved it by inline css with important